# puppeteer: document.querySelector works on console but not on pupppeteer

Tags: puppeteer

when I use the document.querySelector in Chrome console, I obtain something, however when I use the same query with puppeeter. I get "undefined" or "Promise {  }".

```
    const text = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('div.tagCloud-slotAble.space--mv-2 > button:nth-child(1)'));
console.log(text)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the reason you're not able to get your text back and output to your console is happening for two reasons:

- You're not returning the value from your `evaluate` method.
- You're retrieving the element but not the text content from the element.

If you do something like the following, this should resolve your problem:

```
const text = await page.evaluate(() => {
  const uiElement = document.querySelector('div.tagCloud-slotAble.space--mv-2 > button:nth-child(1)'));
  return uiElement.textContent;
});
console.log(text);
```

An alternative to the above function is to use puppeteers `$eval` method as follows:

```
const elementSelector = 'div.tagCloud-slotAble.space--mv-2 > button:nth-child(1)';
const text = await page.$eval(elementSelector, (uiElement) => {
  return uiElement.textContent;
});
console.log(text);
```

I personally prefer the second option (using `$eval`) but it's a matter of preference. Both do the same thing.

It should be noted that anything you run in an `evaluate` or `$eval` method is executed in your **page context** ie. it is executed in the web page which is currently open in the remote browser. You can basically use this method to inject new UI elements into your web page during a test, execute JavaScript code inside your web page etc.

Or you can use it, as you are now, to find a UI element and return the text content from it.

Answer (score 4):

That is because querySelector returns a node. Try to return `innerText`,

```
const text = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('div.tagCloud-slotAble.space--mv-2 > button:nth-child(1)').innerText);
console.log(text)
```

Comment: Hey, indeed i obtain something with .innertext. How come I can display the node on the chrome console but nothing when I use the queryselector with puppeeter ? Thx

Comment: Because puppeteer runs on node context, but chrome console is on browser context. They are seperate thing.

Comment: How comes "document.querySelector('div.tagCloud-slotAble.space--mv-2 > button:nth-child(1)').innerText" works if puppeteer runs on node context ?

Comment: because you are `evaluating/running` this part in the `page`